# How to make ASP.net website developed in old browser ,does not get compatible in all latest browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have developed asp.net website in IE9,but when i am trying to open that website in IE-11,its all layout gets disturb & also when i tries to open in Firefox or crome it does not support Java scripts & its layout gets disturb i.e code written on button click events.
  I used this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

in head portion of my aspx page, for my IE9,it worked,but when i opened same webpage on IE 11, it gave same issue . Above meta tag does not support in firefox or chrome..Any help or any solution,to make it compatible..

Comment: what doesn't work? Please.

Comment: Thanks for reply..actually i have application that is developed in asp.net on VS2008,which is running good on IE9,but when i am trying to open same website in firefox or crome,its layout gets distrub & Link Buttons doest not fire javascript events

Comment: FireFox and Chrome have developer tools.  Are there JS errors in the page?  Press F12 in Chrome or install the FireBug extension for Firefox http://getfirebug.com/ -- dig deeper.

Comment: Change the meta tag to <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> then rewrite your CSS to make it work in modern browsers, against standards. You are telling the browser to emulate IE 7 that way and I am not sure IE 11 actually supports the emulation mode anymore, it would do IE 7 compatibility. But you only want that when your application was written for 2006 era standards, which are not future friendly. So basically you need to update your CSS and write for today's standards and direct IE to use the latest version, 11.